# ListWidget keeps crashin after one run of the method

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

The problem is i got a school project that i got one more week to finish. And basically my code keeps crashing after searching through the file once. For the project we need to do a library like program. The method that is giving me problems is called def isciknjige. It should basically find a book that you are looking for in the file and after searching once it crashes.

Current code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
ls = []

def odprivpis():
    dlg2.show()
    dlg.close()


def odprimain_page():
    dlg.show()
    dlg2.close()

def seznamvsehknjig():
    dlg3.show()
    dlg.close() 

def odpripage4():
    dlg4.show()

def odpripage5():
    seznam = open("baza_knjig.csv", "r")
    seznam = seznam.readlines()
    listWidget = QListWidget()
    listWidget.show()

    ls = []

    for i in seznam:
        listWidget.addItem(i)

    listWidget.addItems(ls)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    seznam.close()

def odpripage6():
    dlg6.show()

def vpis(dat):
    dat=""
    dat=open("Uporabniki.csv","a" , encoding="UTF-8")
    A=str(dlg2.Ime.text())
    B=str(dlg2.Priimek.text())
    C=str(dlg2.Prebivalisce.text())
    D=str(dlg2.Datumrojstva.text())
    E=str(dlg2.ID.text())
    dat.write(A + " / ")
    dat.write(B + " / ")
    dat.write(C + " / ")
    dat.write(D + " / ")
    dat.write(E + " / ")
    dat.close()
    dlg2.close()
    dat.close()

class Knjiznica:
    def __init__(self,naslov,avtor,letoizdaje,zvrst,identifikacija):
        self.naslov=naslov
        self.avtor=avtor
        self.letoizdaje=letoizdaje
        self.identifikacija=identifikacija


def nazaj3():
    dlg3.close()
    dlg.show() 

def nazaj4():
    dlg4.close()
    dlg.show() 
def nazaj5():
    dlg5.close()
    dlg.show() 

def nazaj6():
    dlg6.close()
    dlg.show()

def dodajknjigo(dat2):
    dat2=""
    dat2=open("baza_knjig.csv" , "a" , encoding="UTF-8")
    f=str(dlg6.naslov.text())
    g=str(dlg6.avtor.text())
    h=str(dlg6.leto.text())
    i=str(dlg6.zvrst.text())
    j=str(dlg6.id.text())
    dat2.write(f + " / ")
    dat2.write(g + " / ")
    dat2.write(h + " / ")
    dat2.write(i + " / ")
    dat2.write(j + " / ")
    dat2.close()
    dlg6.close()
    dat2.close()

def isciknjigo(dat3):
    error="Ni zadetkov iskanja."
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    seznam = open("baza_knjig.csv", "r")
    seznam = seznam.readlines()
    listWidget = QListWidget()
    listWidget.show()
    knjiga = str(dlg4.iskanje.text())
    for line in seznam:
        if knjiga in line:
            listWidget.addItem(line)

    dlg4.iskanje.setText("")
    listWidget.addItems(ls)
    app.exec_()

app=QtWidgets.QApplication([])
dlg2=uic.loadUi("vpis.ui")
dlg=uic.loadUi("main_page.ui")
dlg3=uic.loadUi("seznam_knjig.ui")
dlg4=uic.loadUi("isci_knjige.ui")
dlg5=uic.loadUi("baza_knjig.ui")
dlg6=uic.loadUi("dodaj_knjigo.ui")
dlg2.prijava.clicked.connect(vpis)
dlg2.prijava.clicked.connect(odprimain_page)
dlg.prijavi_se_v_sistem.clicked.connect(odprivpis)
dlg.seznam_vseh_knjig.clicked.connect(odpripage5)
dlg.isci_po_knjiznici.clicked.connect(odpripage4)
dlg.dodaj_knjigo.clicked.connect(odpripage6)
dlg3.Nazaj.clicked.connect(nazaj3)
dlg4.Nazaj.clicked.connect(nazaj4)
dlg5.Nazaj.clicked.connect(nazaj5)
dlg6.Nazaj.clicked.connect(nazaj6)
dlg6.dodaj.clicked.connect(dodajknjigo)
dlg4.gumb_isci.clicked.connect(isciknjigo)
dlg.show()
```

(I cant program too good beacuse im only in year 2 of the highschool. And this is quite difficult since we got little help from the beginning.)

Comment: remove `app.exec_()` in isciknjigo and odpripage5 , add `app.exec_()` after `dlg.show()`

Comment: after which dlg.show() am i supposed to put app.exec()? since there are many of them.

Comment: you can only and there must be an app.exec_() so you must remove the others. the app.exec_() must be only in the last line